# RequireJS: Module 'X' has a source path that is same as output path

Tags: javascript, configuration, requirejs

I'm using grunt to build my assets, my `Gruntfile.js` configuration reads as follows:

```
requirejs: {
  build: {
    options: {
      almond: true,
      appDir: '.tmp',
      findNestedDependencies: true,
      mainConfigFile: '.tmp/scripts/config.js',
      modules: [
        { name: 'mod' },
      ],
      dir: 'public',
      optimize: 'uglify',
      optimizeCss: 'standard',
      preserveLicenseComments: false,
      relativeUrl: './',
      skipDirOptimize: true,
      useStrict: true
    }
  }
},
```

So technically the configuration is telling RequireJS to build the module inside `public/scripts/mod.js` out of `.tmp/scripts/mod.js`.

**Why RequireJS insist that the path is the same as the output?**

```
Running "requirejs:build" (requirejs) task
{ [Error: Error: Module ID 'mod' has a source path that is same as output path: /Users/ivan/project/.tmp/scripts/mod.js. Stopping, config is malformed.
    at /Users/ivan/project/node_modules/requirejs/bin/r.js:25834:39
]
  originalError: [Error: Module ID 'mod' has a source path that is same as output path: /Users/ivan/project/.tmp/scripts/mod.js. Stopping, config is malformed.] }
```

Answer (score -1, accepted):

It seems, you have single module to optimize - you shouldn't use modules then. Try this:

```
requirejs: {
  build: {
    options: {
      almond: true,
      findNestedDependencies: true,
      mainConfigFile: '.tmp/scripts/config.js',
      name : 'mod'
      out: 'public/result.js',
      optimize: 'uglify',
      optimizeCss: 'standard',
      preserveLicenseComments: false,
      relativeUrl: './',
      skipDirOptimize: true,
      useStrict: true
    }
  }
},
```

This should work. I hope, I understood your configuration well. If not - let me know.

Comment: Well, I'm in fact creating multiple modules. I just removed them from the configuration to simplify the above example.

Comment: I tried the way you suggested, and it works. But only to build one module. I can multiple configs I guess, one per module in my configuration using concurrent. Thanks!

Comment: @IvanTorres I think, main problem in your example is in ```appDir``` field. Maybe you may not specify it - you specify mainConfigFile anyway.

Comment: Is `relativeUrl` an actual option? I can't locate any references to it in the docs or in the source.

Answer (score 1):

This seems to be a [problem caused by an r.js commit](https://github.com/asciidisco/grunt-requirejs/issues/87) itself whereby setting buildPath and sourcePath results in an exception being raised. You could try using an earlier release of r.js to solve the problem.

Answer (score 1):

I've actually faced the same problem, and the previous post's author is right: it is a r.js problem related to overriding source files during building.

As I see, they have added a config option `allowSourceOverwrites` to fix it:
[r.js config example](https://github.com/jrburke/r.js/blob/master/build/example.build.js#L646)

Setting it to `true` helped me, and hope would help someone else.